# shell record UDP stream from a specific address

Tags: udp, tcpdump, netcat

I'm trying to record an incoming UDP stream (stream the sense that it's a stream of consecutive datagrams).

I tried `netcat` but unfortunately *multiple sources* send data on the same port address and `nc` doesn't let you specify the source or the target multicast address.

Then I tried `tcpdump -w -` because tcpdump has rich filtering options, but it records the raw stream and I only need the actual data so I can process it like it were a stream. Unfortunately it records all the packet related info like source/destination or IP/UDP headers.

Is there a way to do this? I could write a small C program to do this but I prefer to use existing tools.

Answer (score 2):

My first choose would be wireshark. If you must do it from a terminal you can also try ngrep, it gives a more readable output than tcpdump. You can probably filter out the header info with a simple bash script.

http://ngrep.sourceforge.net/usage.html#http

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`wireshark`](http://www.wireshark.org). It can do what you want plus more.

`wireshark` is not useful if what you want is to receive the data in the stream and feed it to a program. In that case, I would have to say that you are using the wrong protocol. If I were in your place I would *cheat*.

Hopefully you are on Linux. In that case, make a firewall rewrite rule to send incoming UDP packets from the desired source that are sent to the proper port to another port where you can use netcat to record the data in the stream.

This [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/211536/iptables-port-redirect-not-working-for-localhost) will help you start.

Comment: I want to feed a command line app with the stream...

Comment: firewall rule is an interesting idea, thx. I'll stick to the C program, as it's sounds more logic.

Answer (score 0):

[netsed](http://silicone.homelinux.org/projects/netsed/) or iptables + [the libnetfilter_queue module](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/index.html) or ngrep might do what you wish.