# iptables preroute localhost

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firewall, iptables, ip

I would like to forward all incoming traffic from a certain port to another one using iptables. The problem is that prerouting doesn't work for traffic from localhost. This [topic](https://serverfault.com/questions/211536/iptables-port-redirect-not-working-for-localhost) suggests a solution:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

This solution does work for most cases. However, when I connect to http://myserver:443 where myserver resolves to an IP address that is hosted on the local machine, but is not 127.0.0.1 it seems to bypass both rules.

Is there a way to also catch forwards requests from the local machine that are done to the eth0 ip address?

Comment: Here's a really useful answer:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111433/iptables-redirect-outside-requests-to-127-0-0-1

Comment: Note that it can be dangerous to do the REDIRECTs blind like that, if the server is also acting as a firewall (as in one case when I wanted to do something like this), such a rule will manipulate all outgoing (routed) connections as well from the internal network to the external! In those cases you need to qualify them with one or several -d's (I couldn't find any more general solution)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of doing `-d 127.0.0.1` on the OUTPUT rule, you could do `-o lo`. This will match any traffic going through the loopback interface no matter what the destination is.

As a side note, even when you send to 'http://myserver:443', the traffic is still local, so it still goes through the loopback interface, even though it doesnt resolve to '127.0.0.1'.

Comment: This helped me (using -o lo) for REDIRECTing internal connections!