# Port 80 redirect does not work for localhost

Tags: linux, web-server, python, ubuntu-12.04

I want to run a simple python webserver on my ubuntu linode with the following command (it simply puts the current dir up on the port specified)

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

I am using port 8080 to avoid using sudo to run on port 80

To make it accessible I redirect port 80 to port 8080 with the following command:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Now any computer can access my website giuliopizzini.com EXCEPT localhost which gets a socket error, connection refused. If I point localhost to giuliopizzini.com:8080 it works OK but the redirect fails.

I have firewall enabled but if I reset it with

```
sudo iptables -F
```

the behavior is exactly the same, so that does not seem to play a role here.

How can I make the redirect work on localhost as well?

Comment: Related http://serverfault.com/questions/211536/iptables-port-redirect-not-working-for-localhost

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add another rule for localhost redirection to work:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d localhost -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

You need to include the destination IP you are using to connect such as localhost or any interface IP.

Locally-generated traffic does not hit the `PREROUTING` chain. It hits the `OUTPUT` chain in the nat table which is what the above rule is doing.

Comment: It worked like a charm putting the machine IP in place of `localhost` in your rule above. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried this rule but nothing changes... Which can be the problem? I've written this post: http://serverfault.com/questions/745554/opensuse-port-forwarding-80-to-8080-not-working