# Opensuse port forwarding 80 to 8080 not working

Tags: networking, iptables, port-forwarding, opensuse, glassfish

I've a glassfish server that use the port 8080.

I need forward from port 80 to 8080 so I can access the content without put the :8080 port in the url.

I've tried to put a masquerade rule, add iptables rules but nothing changes...

The last iptables rule that i've tried is:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d localhost -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

That come from this post [Port 80 redirect does not work for localhost](https://serverfault.com/questions/464410/port-80-redirect-does-not-work-for-localhost) the problem is that nothing changes.

The version of opensuse is: 13.2

What I miss?

Answer (score 1):

Try below iptables rules, it should work for you

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Also SuSEfirewall2 regenerates the iptables on each boot. So if you want to save rules then you can add "custom rules" using the file:
/etc/sysconfig/scripts/SuSEfirewall2-custom

Comment: I've execute the commands that you said, but going to http://localhost the page not appear...

Comment: tested to work like a charm in SLES15. In theory, should work for other flavours too!