# iptables port forwarding has no effect when server&client on the same machine?

Tags: linux, iptables

I have a web server running on port 8080. I'd like to visit it via port 80, so I did this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

it works if i access the server from other machines using

```
http://ipoftheserver/
```

but it doesn't work if I access the server from the same machine using

```
http://localhost/
```

why is that?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do what you want via iptables, localhost doesn't go through the NAT routing. See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891380/iptables-port-redirection-wont-work-for-localhost) and this [SF question](https://serverfault.com/questions/211536/iptables-port-redirect-not-working-for-localhost) for details.

You can make the server bind to multiple ports if it's `Apache`. See this page for details, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html.

#### `httpd.conf`

```
Listen 80
Listen 8000
```

-or-

```
Listen 192.0.2.1:80
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
Listen 192.0.2.1:8000
```

Answer (score 3):

The `PREROUTING` chain affects received packets before they are routed. Locally-generated packets start at the `OUTPUT` chain.