# Lighttpd Reverse Proxy with SSL/HTTPS

Tags: ssl, lighttpd

I am trying configure Lighttpd to redirect/handle port-specific requests to a subdomain.

I can access my plex server via `https://www.example.com:32400/`

I would like that to be redirected to `https://plex.example.com/`

I have the following config, but there isn't any SSL associated with the link.  SSL is working fine on the main page, but nothing else.

```
$HTTP["host"] == "plex.example.com" {
    proxy.server  = ( "" => ( (
            "host" => "127.0.0.1",
            "port" => 32400
    ) ) )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See: https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModProxy

> lighttpd mod_proxy is a reverse proxy. lighttpd mod_proxy does not currently support SSL/TLS connections to the backend server.

If you want to use lighttpd as your reverse proxy, you would need to disable HTTPS on the backend (Plex) service.

Other tools would work, like a [port forward using iptables](https://serverfault.com/a/211544/146236). (This assumes tht the application does not use absolute links to itself, for which a more complicated solution, like Apache's `mod_proxy_html` to rewrite modifiy the returned data to fix the links)

Comment: can we first terminate TLS in lighttpd then redirect HTTP only?

Comment: @VincentAlex You should be able to set up a HTTPS site in lighttpd that just redirects to HTTP (The answer is more about where the backend behind the proxy is running HTTPS instead of HTTP)

Comment: This is a joke. Why this is not supported?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you control the backend server, you can use an unprivileged SSH tunnel from the front-end server to the backend to add transport-layer encryption. SSH session multiplexing can help reduce latency.