# How to forward ports via iptables while making that port also being listened?

Tags: iptables

I'm forwarding a port from my HOST (`192.168.1.4@MY_LAN`) to my virtual machine (`10.0.10.5@HOST`) with the following `iptables` rule:

```
HOST:~$ iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.0.10.5:80
```

If I make a request to `192.168.1.4:80` inside `MY_LAN`, I get the correct response.

However, port 80 isn't being listened on the HOST:

```
HOST:~$ netstat -anp | grep 80 | grep -w LISTEN
# nothing shown here
```

...so I can not connect to `HOST:80` within my `VPN_SERVER` when I connect my HOST to VPN:

```
VPN_SERVER:~$ curl http://192.168.30.11:80
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.30.11 port 80: Connection refused
```

If I forward the connection with `socat`, everything works correctly (based on [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/803643/371730)):

```
HOST:~$ sudo socat TCP-LISTEN:80,su=nobody,fork,reuseaddr TCP-CONNECT:10.0.10.5:80
```

```
VPN_SERVER:~$ curl http://192.168.30.11:80
<html>
<head><title>Hello world!</title></head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

## Question

How can I get rid of this `socat` workaround and make this type of connection possible by using only `iptables`?

Comment: Don't use NAT here. Use normal IP routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things:

1. Port forwarding works without listen sockets, it just rewrites destination address and/or port. So empty listen sockets list for your forwarded port number is a normal situation.
2. Local originated packets (from `HOST` itself) don't pass the `POSTROUTING` chain. You should add another one `DNAT` rule under the `nat/OUTPUT` chain:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT \
         -d 192.168.30.11 \
         -p tcp --dport 80 \
    -j DNAT --to 10.0.10.5:80
```

Comment: We also need [`sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1`](https://serverfault.com/a/856121/261445) for `localhost:PORT` syntax to work.

Answer (score 0):

I thing it is a routing problem

Try add masquerade rule. Somtething like this:

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -d 10.10.10.5 -j MASQUERADE