# Redirect IP:Port to another IP:Port on the same machine

Tags: iptables

My server has 8 IP addresses that I can use. I want to redirect 51.x.x.**73**:443 to 51.x.x.**72**:25565, which are all on the same machine. Port 80 and 443 is already occupied on .72 so I can’t use that IP. How should I go about this?

I used this solution ([iptables port redirect not working for localhost](https://serverfault.com/questions/211536/iptables-port-redirect-not-working-for-localhost)) before, but can’t anymore because port 443 is now occupied on my .72 IP.

I could do a KVM or some virtualization to make a reverse nginx proxy but that would be an overly complicated solution. Is there a way to do this easily in IP tables or similar?

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. I don't understand why you would need this: is there an app running in the background?

Comment: @LeRouteur It's called Minecraft.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I noticed it but a little bit too late, my bad.