# iptables and Nginx reverse proxy for localhost

Tags: nginx, iptables, reverse-proxy

#### Summary

I use Nginx as a reverse proxy and in particular its functionality `proxy_bind` in order to send the real client IP to the backend. I followed [this documentation from nginx.com](https://www.nginx.com/blog/ip-transparency-direct-server-return-nginx-plus-transparent-proxy/#ip-transparency).
It works well, both when the HTTP server is hosted on another machine or directly on the one of the reverse proxy, except in the second case if the HTTP server listens on localhost.

**=> I can't get this configuration works:**

```sh
# /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-revprox-test.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_bind  $remote_addr transparent;
    }
}
```

#### Details

> Hypotheses:
>
> - IP addresses:
>
>   - Reverse proxy/Local backend: `192.168.1.90 (eth0)` & `172.17.0.1 (eth1)`
>   - External backend: `172.17.0.2`
>   - Client: `192.168.1.91`
> - Ports:
>
>   - frontend: `80` (no TLS)
>   - backends: `8080`

- **Case n°1**: The HTTP server is hosted on the external backend (http://172.17.0.2:8080).

  ```sh
  # /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-revprox-test.conf
  server {
      listen 192.168.1.90:80;
      location / {
          proxy_pass  http://172.17.0.2:8080;
          proxy_bind  $remote_addr transparent;
      }
  }
  ```

  The [manual](https://www.nginx.com/blog/ip-transparency-direct-server-return-nginx-plus-transparent-proxy/#ip-transparency) says we have to configure iptables consequently:

  ```sh
  iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s 172.17.0.2 --sport 8080 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x1/0xffffffff
  ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup 100
  ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100
  ```

  => It works fine.
- **Case n°2**: The HTTP server is hosted on the same machine than the reverse proxy and listens on `eth1` (http://172.17.0.1:8080).

  ```sh
  # /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-revprox-test.conf
  server {
      listen 192.168.1.90:80;
      location / {
          proxy_pass  http://172.17.0.1:8080;
          proxy_bind  $remote_addr transparent;
      }
  }
  ```

  According to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/211544/866485) and [this diagram](http://linux-ip.net/nf/nfk-traversal.png), only *OUTPUT* and *POSTROUTING* apply to locally generated packets. We need to change our iptables rule consequently:

  ```sh
  iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s 172.17.0.2 --sport 8080 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x1/0xffffffff
  ```

  => It works too.
- **Case n°3**: The HTTP server is hosted locally but listen on `lo` (http://127.0.0.1:8080).

  ```sh
  # /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-revprox-test.conf
  server {
      listen 192.168.1.90:80;
      location / {
          proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080;
          proxy_bind  $remote_addr transparent;
      }
  }
  ```

  => **[!]** I can't get it works, even with an *OUTPUT* rule in iptables.
  `curl http://192.168.1.90:80` does not work from the client (it only works from the server but that's not the point).

I missed something about iptables. Could you help me?

Comment: Precision: the third case without `proxy_bind` works fine, but we of course lose IP transparency.

Comment: I would implement passing the real IP address in a header and then the backend would use that IP address. Performing routing table hacks to achieve this goal makes the solution harder to understand.

Comment: cant you also set a custom header? NGINX can this, but your app?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid Netfilter marking for case 3 - the necessary filtering is also supported directly by `ip rule`. The following will route all traffic from the backend server to the nginx frontend:

```bash
# add a new routing table that routes all packets back to this server
ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100

# add a rule for choosing that routing table:
ip rule add from 127.0.0.1/32 ipproto 6 sport 8080 iif lo lookup 100
# ^ individual parts:
# from 127.0.0.1/32 - select just one loopback IP, the one with nginx on it
# ipproto 6  - select just TCP
# sport 8080 - select just traffic from the backend HTTP server port
# iif lo     - select just traffic originating from this machine
# lookup 100 - route these matching packets via routing table 100
```

I found this by trial-and-error with the help of [`ip rule`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-rule.8.html) manpage and the packet flow diagram ([1](https://help.mikrotik.com/docs/display/ROS/Packet+Flow+in+RouterOS#PacketFlowinRouterOS-OverallPacketflowDiagram), [2](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Netfilter-packet-flow.svg)).

---

You could also use Netfilter marking, but I would recommend the solution above as it avoids enabling `route_localnet` (**which can cause [security issues](https://unit42.paloaltonetworks.com/cve-2020-8558/)**). For completeness, this is how to make it work:

1. Enable routing on local interfaces (as per https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/158256/72419):

   ```bash
   sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=0
   ```
2. Configure the routing table:

   ```bash
   ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup 100
   ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100
   ```
3. Let Netfilter mark the packet in the OUTPUT chain:

   ```
   iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s 127.0.0.1 --sport 8080 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x1/0xffffffff
   ```

   The OUTPUT chain is critical - locally produced packets do not go through the PREROUTING table.

You might be able to avoid the security issues associated with `route_localnet`, though - https://github.com/yrutschle/sslh/blob/master/doc/tproxy.md#transparent-proxy-to-one-host fixes this with

```bash
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING ! -i lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING ! -o lo -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
```